# CSS Typewriter Effect Starting from the Middle/Right to Left

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, ejs

For my website I’m making a typewriter effect for the title of the page. It half-way finished but its not working the way I wanted it to be. The typewriter effect starts in the middle and “types” left and right at the same time. It was intended to start from the left and end on the right but its not working. How can I make it the way it was intended to be?

```css
.line {
    width: 40em;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 260px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.anim-typewriter {
    animation: typewriter 4s steps(40) 1s 1 normal both,
    blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(40) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
    from {
        width: 0;
    }
    to {
        width: 40em;
    }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
    from {
        border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    }
    to {
        border-right-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center head line anim-typewriter">
    <h1><b>Maintain the best Example Server.</b></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is the right answer to you. Just remove the text-align: middle;

```
.line {
    width: 40em;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    font-size: 100%;
    // remove this: text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 260px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or maybe the happening comes from the class: justify-content-center

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center head line anim-typewriter">
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!